# MS SQL query for totals based on a time to determine peak volumes over a time period

Tags: sql-server, datetime, volumes

I have a database with a lot of records and each record has a datetime and filesize (in bytes) captured against it.

Table:

```
ID          DateTime                   FileSize
000001      2013-01-01 01:00:07        1535112
000002      2013-01-01 01:00:08        2506843
```

and so on

I want a query to determine peak volume in a given time period. for example in any 10 minute window if total of file size exceed 200MB then I want to know that 10 minute window. I am not sure if running total would be ideal but I am not sure how to calculate it.

Cheers.

Comment: I am not really clear what you are looking for. Do you want to know the busiest time of day or do you want a 10 minute window that has the most filesize or do you want to find all 10 minutes windows in day where the total filesize is > 200MB? How do you defined the start and end of these windows?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, hopefully it's not too slow:

```
select
    T.DateTime,
    D.Total
from table T
cross apply (
    select sum(FileSize) as Total 
    from table T2 
    where T2.DateTime >= T.DateTime and 
      T2.DateTime < dateadd(minute, 10, T2.DateTime)
) D
where
  D.Total > 200000000
```

This can of still bring several hits for a longer period if the amount exceeds the limit.